# retrieve database values in register page in laravel

Tags: laravel, mariadb, laravel-authentication

I have registration auth in laravel project and i need some existing datas should show up on the registration form , please guide me up..

```
http://165.232.187.63/register
```

This is my register page and i need to fetch existing database values in the  registration form. for example

```
    <select>
@foreach($users as $items) 
      <option>{{ $items->id }}</option>
@endforeach
    </select>
```

How to customize this...

I have tried adding in `web.php` file

```
Route::get('/register','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserController@index');
```

And in my `UserController.php`

```
   public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('auth.register')
           ->with('users', $users);
}
```

But can't use both post and get for register auth

Comment: Why do you want all user records on register page?

Comment: I gave this for example.. I just want the last registered user id alone

Comment: Omar gave you the right answer for your question. But I'm still interested why would you need existing user record on your register page, it's unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate endpoints for this task
one to load the view

```
Route::get('/register','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserController@index');
```

and the other to do the actual registration

```
Route::post('/register','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserController@register');
```

of course in the UserController, you will have a register method that handles the actual registration process